# GridView getView method called multiple times while loading images from server causing scrolling very slow

Tags: android, gridview

I am using a gridview with image adapter. The adapter load images from web and show in gridview. The problem is that when I scroll down and scroll up again, the images that has been already loaded are being loaded again slowing the scrolling. Any Idea...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its beacause each time a new imageview is created.reuse the convertview that you  pass to your getview() method of the image adapter.